# How do I run a Stored Procedure in SQL Developer when DBAs won't allow SYS.DBMS_SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to run my Stored Procedure using SQL Developer, but the DBAs refuse to allow SYS.DBMS_SQL on some databases.

Is there an easy way to modify the PL/SQL to work around it?

Simple Example of Test Code is:

```
DECLARE
  I_NUM1 NUMBER;
  O_NUM2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  I_NUM1 := 1;

  P_PACKAGE_1_0.GET_VALUE (
       I_NUM1 => I_NUM1, 
       O_NUM2 => O_NUM2 );
END;
```

Comment: What does the example have to do with dbms_sql? I appreciate that it is frustrating when arbitrary tools are prohibited for no good reason, but I am not sure what you are asking exactly.

Comment: Does your p_package_1_0.get value use dbms_sql in some way?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough situation, and is more of a question about office politics than programming.  But some programming knowledge can arm you to have a more fruitful discussion with the DBAs.

**History (and some speculation)**

Almost all Oracle security policies and audits are based on the Department of Defense Secure Technical Implementation Guidelines.  Even if you hire an expensive auditor, I bet they'll use the same scripts provided for free by the government.

A long time ago, the 11g version of the documents recommended removing DBMS_SQL from `PUBLIC`, because *reasons*.  It was a bad decision, probably based on a bug in an early version of Oracle.  If there was a security hole in an Oracle package it should be fixed with a patch, not by removing the package.

If you follow those rules, read the documents carefully.  They only require removing privileges from `PUBLIC`.  You are allowed to grant access to individuals as needed.  And the 12c version of the STIG doesn't remove any of the default packages anymore.

What you do with this information is up to you.  You could try to be a friend to the DBAs, and say, "Hey, I don't think you need to enforce this rule anymore, which will make your lives much simpler since you don't have to break objects when you revoke privileges."  Or you could be a jerk, and demand documented proof of the rules, and then accuse them of not following modern security standards.  I recommend trying to have a friendly discussion with someone.

**Workarounds**

Are you sure you need `SYS.DBMS_SQL`?  How about `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, or `DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML`?  There are several ways to run dynamic code in Oracle.